# Operation between one list and all other remaining lists excluding the operation between the selected list itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is working well. Is there a way to minimize the complexity of the code?

```
final = []
a = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp = []
    for k in range(len(a)):
        m = 0
        if i != k:
            for j in range(0, len(a)):
                DIFFERENCE = (a[i][j] - a[k][j])**2
                m += DIFFERENCE
                p = (1/(2 * m)) * DIFFERENCE
            temp.append(p)
    final.append(temp)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this operation? Maybe better alternatives exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` in conjunction with `itertools` for this.

First, [`itertools.permutations("ABCD", 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) gives `AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC`, i.e. the combination of each element with each other, including `AB` and `BA`, but excluding the combination of each element with itself (so `AA`).

With this we can use simple numpy element-wise operations:

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

def graipher(a):
    a = np.array(a)  # to make sure, better call this outside and remove it here
    final = []
    for x, y in permutations(a, 2):
        d = (x - y)**2
        m = d.sum()
        final.append(d[-1] / (2*m))
    return np.array(final).reshape(len(a), -1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
    print(graipher(a).tolist())
# [[0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666],
#  [0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666],
#  [0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]]
```

For the small example you gave, this is not actually faster (but also not slower). It is also a lot more readable, IMO.

For a random sample of shape 100 x 100, this code takes about 33 ms to compute the final result, whereas yours takes more than a second.

---

Some comments on your code explicitly:

- Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is well worth a read. It recommends using `lower_case` for variable (and function) names.
- In your innermost loop, you calculate `p` every iteration, but only the last iteration contains the value you care about. You can therefore pull it out of the loop.
- Your code works only for `n x n` inputs, whereas the algorithm (and my code) works for `n x k` inputs.